# Manual add/delete/edit records in sqlite database in Andorid Eclipse emulator?

Tags: android

Is there way to add, edit or delete records manually in sqlite database in Android Eclipse emulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open shell to your emulator device using adb :

```
  adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

then you can use the sqlite3 to get into sqlite shell :

```
#sqlite3
sqlite3
SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite>
```

You can execute SQLs here. See if that helps.

You can also open the database as below by going to the directory where you have your database:

```
#sqlite3 mydatabase.db
```